# Swift - edit last item of array of struct

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose we have a struct

```
struct Item {
    var text: String
}
```

and array of it

```
var items: [Item] = [Item(text:"aa"), Item(text:"bb"), Item(text:"cc")]
```

And we want to update text of the last item of that array. My first version looked like this:

```
if var item = self.items.last {
    item.text = "dd"
}
```

But because it is struct, the item is copied and the array is not modified. First solution would be to change struct to class, but I don't think that is actually a good solution, and neither is my final approach

```
if self.items.last != nil {
    self.items[self.items.count - 1].text = "dd"
}
```

Is there better way?

Comment: The last one obviously works, doesn't it? If you want a cleaner, more sophisticated answer, you can create a class. But I don't feel that your current working solution is bad.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here should work like charm:

```
if self.items.last != nil {
    self.items[self.items.count - 1].text = "dd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can edit last item of array of struct.

```
struct Item {
    var text: String
}
var items: [Item] = [Item(text:"aa"), Item(text:"bb"), Item(text:"cc")]  //[{text "aa"}, {text "bb"}, {text "cc"}]
if items.last != nil {
    items[items.count - 1].text = "dd"
} 
items                                                                    //[{text "aa"}, {text "bb"}, {text "dd"}]
```

Tested with playground.

If you want to do it with `items.last!.text = "dd"` then it is not possible because `Array.last` is read Only property which have only get as you can see in below image:

[image]

Which will only return a last element from array and if it is not there then it will return `nil`. So you can not assign any value to it.

Comment: I'm seeking for better solution. Perhaps solution like items.last!.text = "dd" but it actually don't work.